# Does $\# \mathsf{P}\subseteq \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{PH}}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity

The Toda's theorem is a relationship between two different complexity classes: $ \# \mathsf{P} $ and  $PH$. He proved that $ \mathsf{PH}\subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}} $.

I wonder the following statement holds.

> $ $    $\#\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{PH}}$

If we prove this statement, $\# \mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{PH}$, that is, counting and alternation are $roughly$ $equivalent$ classes.

Answer (score 9):

If your statement holds, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses: $\mathsf{\# P} \subseteq \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{PH}}$ iff $\mathsf{\# P} \subseteq \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{\Sigma_k P}}$ for some fixed $k$ (by definition). But then by Toda's Theorem we have $\mathsf{PH} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{\# P}} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{\Sigma_k P}}} = \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{\Sigma_k P}} = \mathsf{\Delta_{k+1} P}$.

Comment: Does $NP\subseteq P^{Mod_{k} P}$ and $coNP\subseteq P^{Mod_{k'} P}$ imply $PH\subseteq P^{Mod_{k''} P}$ at some $k''$?

Comment: @777: $PH \subseteq P^{Mod_k P}$ unconditionally.

Comment: I thought only PH in BPP^ModkP is known unconditionally.

Comment: @777: Oh, sorry, you're right. The answer to your original question is yes, just take $k'' = k k'$ and use the fact that if $a | b$ then $Mod_a P \subseteq Mod_b P$. Then you get that both $NP,coNP$ are contained in $P^{Mod_{kk'} P}$, and you can do the usual thing to get the whole of $PH$ in there. I think you also need the fact that $Mod_a P$ is low for itself.

Comment: sorry the steps are unclear to me. How does proof $NP\cup coNP\subset P^{Mod_aP}$ implies $PH\subset P^{Mod_aP}$ work?

Comment: @777: A good fraction of my time on this site is spent answering *your* questions, including questions like this that you ask in the comments, which are not really what the comments are for. Nonetheless, this suggests an overlap of interests. If you want an answer to this one, please email me. It would be nice to know who you are and, much more importantly, have a real conversation that doesn't fit into this public and character-limited format. Sincerely, Josh.